# How can I retrieve the current command name in a Thor method?

Tags: ruby, thor

I have several Thor tasks depending on each other. I'd like to have access to the name of the one currently running so that I can use it in the logger messages.

I can use the `self` object to find the task name but that's a `Thor::Sandbox::MyClass` object and that piece of information is deeply positioned. Does anybody know a getter? Something like:

```
class MyCLI < Thor
  def hello
    puts "hello, I am the task #{self.taskname}"
  end
end
```

Comment: What does `self.to_s` returns?

Comment: to_s returns #<Thor::Sandbox::Idrico:0x00000100ed2ac8>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this would work:

```
def fun
 puts __method__
end

fun
#=> :fun
```

Also look in the [`caller`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-caller) method. It returns the current execution stack as a string.

Comment: `__method__` works tnx. `caller` is worse than `.self` to parse.